# How can I get the text in the bottom left of my buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align the text in the buttons to the bottom left corner of the buttons, but no amount of padding seems to work! Someone please help me do this. Here is what I have.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y5GH/)

**CSS**

```
 .button {
     width: 187px;
     height: 187px;
     border: none;
     margin-bottom: 11px;
     margin-right: 11px;
     display:inline-block;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
 }
 .text {
     position: absolute;
     padding-top: 65px;
     padding-right: 35px;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: white;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="column">
    <div class="row">
        <button class="button"> <span class="text"></span>

        </button>
        <button class="button"> <span class="text"></span>

        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `padding` works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cVLQN/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/74DL3/2/)

Add `position: relative` to `.button`

```
.button {
    position:relative;
    width: 187px;
    height: 187px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

<div class="row">
   <button class="button">
       <span class="text">Button</span>
   </button>
   <button class="button">
       <span class="text">Button</span>
   </button>
</div>
```